# Sharepoint Web Part CAB Deployment Failing - Missing Resource file

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, cab

**Issue:** When attempting to add a custom Web Part to a Sharepoint site, addition fails with 'File Not Found' Error.  Checking the 12\LOGS indicates a resource file issue: 
**#20015: Cannot open "Resources.en-US.resx": no such file or folder.**

I have looked in all the normal suspect places (12\Resources, etc..).  I have no Resources.resx to rename.  Furthermore, I have not used a resource file in my development.

**Setup:**
Currently, I have 4 Web Parts in a single Project.  Manifest.XML is set up and good to go.  I also have 3 other projects (DAL, BLL type of stuff) that have their primary output added to the CAB project.  I'm running stsadm -o addwppack with the -globalinstall and -force options.  (I have attempted an -o addsolution option, after re-wiring my manifest.xml, but I'm getting the same issue).  I can verify all .dll's are added to the GAC.

**Question:** What am I missing here?  2 days spent with google and reworking my cab project have not helped.  The sad thing is, deployment from Visual Studio works.  However, I'm needing to deploy to the next enivornment up and I do not have rights to that machine (plus, there's no way I'll be able to get Vis Studio onto the Production box).  Any help or pointers are appreciated (as I am currently at my wits end with SharePoint).  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps: Resource files live in the physical path for the site zone (usually the one set during the Web Application creation), such as:

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\myportal80\, you will find the resource files in the App_GlobalResources folder.

In Visual Studio, can you confirm that when you go to all your subprojects in the solution => properties => Resources, it says **This project does not contain a default resources files. Click here to create one** ?

Comment: Check and Check.  That is what is throwing me for a loop.  I don't have a Resources.resx ANYWHERE, nor do any of my projects have a Resources.resx indicated.

Comment: Then I would go with reverse engineering -- remove the assemblies referenced (your DAL/BLL), start with a simple webpart and build up from there. Sorry not being able to be more useful

Comment: No, I understand.  That's where I'm at now (with the reverse engineering).  Thanks though.